# Obj C and class-dump protection

Tags: objective-c, macos

I understand that it is easy to hack Mach-O executable, I just want simple protection against "class-dump" tool. Is there any tool or XCode plugin that can change all classes names and class functions to something not very readable (like random combination of symbols and numbers)?

Frankly that's all protection I need.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is may turn out to be a fruitless effort: delegate methods must keep their names, and xib connections easily give away the actual purpose of any class or method. You had better also write your own message resolver which takes part in the garbling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a bit about this in [this blog post](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2010/07/20/), but to summarise: you can avoid having methods appearing in `class-dump` by registering them at runtime, or just keeping them as functions.

If really *all* you want to do is rename the classes/methods, you can [use the `tops` command-line tool](http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2009/07/refactor-your-code-from-command-line.html) or Xcode's refactoring feature.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Objective C obfuscators](http://www.google.com.br/#hl=pt-BR&source=hp&biw=996&bih=787&q=obj+c+obfuscator&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=30ca9fa27ee7ba2c)?

[This page](http://robnapier.net/blog/obfuscating-cocoa-389) has a great discussion on **Obfuscating Cocoa**.

Comment: it is not hackers/crackers I'm worried about. I have freeware utility, and I want to protect it from annoying competitors, which are very curious "what's inside". Changing functions/classes names will be enough to stop them :) I googled for 'obj c obfuscator' but everybody is recommending that it will not help - they will crack your shareware - well it is not my case

Comment: @user564068 I'm not aware of any tools that will do that for Obj C.

Answer (score 1):

You *really* probably don't want to bother with this. Obfuscation will not prevent a determined hacker from reverse engineering a truly valuable algorithm. Casual users won't bother, so you're likely doing a lot of work for little added value. As @mvds points out in a comment to your question, NIB connections will betray the purpose of many classes and a determined hacker could use dtrace/Instruments.app to trace messages to uncover much of the rest of what they need.

Any truly valuable IP needs to be protected by something stronger than obfuscation and should probably be written in C/C++ as well as having legal patent and copyright protection (and enforcement).

Comment: Yes, I understand about Nib connections, but it is not hackers/crackers I'm worried about. I have freeware utility, and I want to protect it from annoying competitors, which are very curious "what's inside". Changing functions/classes names will be enough to stop them :) I googled for 'obj c obfuscator' but everybody is recommending that it will not help - they will crack your shareware - well it is not my case

Comment: Don't bother.  If you want to protect what is inside, file a patent or take other legal protection.  Once distributed, the workings of your app are abundantly apparent to anyone with a bit of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing already, you can at least strip your executable of certain unnecessary symbols by enabling 'Deployment Postprocessing' and 'Strip Linked Product 'in the Xcode build setting. (Or just use the `strip` tool directly.) Better than nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately strip doesn't help. class-dump output is absolutely same before and after strip